# How can I make my picker options render as a box instead of a spinner?

Tags: xamarin.forms

On Android, my picker is rendering as this

[image: Spinner Style]

I'd prefer it render as this

[image: Non Spinner]

It's not the color that I'm having a hard time with, it's that it's being rendered as a spinner and I don't want that.

I'm populating the picker by data binding to the ItemsSource property as described here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource

Here's my picker

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding AmountFrequencyStrategies}" />
```

Here's my view model

```
    private List<string> amountFrequencyStrategies;

    public PageViewModel()
    {
        this.amountFrequencyStrategies = new List<string>{ "one", "two", "three"};
    }

    public List<string> AmountFrequencyStrategies => this.amountFrequencyStrategies;
```

My version of xamarin.forms is 3.0.0.482510

My android manifest file has the following line

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
```

Comment: Post duplicated on Xamarin Forums: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/128479/how-can-i-make-my-android-picker-options-render-as-a-box-instead-of-a-spinner/p1?new=1 . I added an answer there.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to write your own renderer for the picker, or not use the picker at all and roll your own cross platform UI for picking items. The built in Xamarin Forms picker renders to a Spinner on Android as you experienced.

Guide on custom renderers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

You might want to look over the source for the Xamarin.Forms Picker Renderer on Android to give you some idea of how to make your own and not use a Spinner:
Not using AppCompat: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/PickerRenderer.cs
using AppCompat:
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/PickerRenderer.cs

And actually it looks like they are not using a Spinner. On the non-AppCompat renderer it looks like just an Android NumberPicker is used :
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/PickerRenderer.cs#L110

And on AppCompat version of the PickerRenderer, it looks like an alert dialog is used:
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/PickerRenderer.cs#L109

Comment: Thank you -- you just saved my bacon.  I was trying to figure out why my PickerRenderer itself was rendering differently than a normal Picker -- turns out I needed to derive from  Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer and not  Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PickerRenderer

That's crazy!  Per OP -- you may want to consider doing the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was also wondering, after I migrated our MainActivity to derive FormsAppCompatActivity I was so glad the Picker was looking more modern, like an alert dialog. Then I wrote a custom renderer and boom, it went back to the old crappy style. Now when I derive from AppCompat.PickerRenderer, everything's back to aces.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this: [Bindable Picker Control for Xamarin.Forms](https://blog.xamarin.com/new-bindable-picker-control-for-xamarin-forms/)
Hope it may solve your issue

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my question to show that I'm doing things just like the article you reference. Unfortunately the picker is still the spinner type.

Comment: What is the version of Xamarin.Forms in your Project?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the version of Xamarin.Forms

Comment: I have tried the sample Project for Xamarin.Forms version 2.3.4.270 and its working fine as expected, If its possible downgrade to this version and try!

Comment: I've downgrade the project and still see the spinner type. I know I'm missing something here. Thanks for your help on this. I'm going to continue to try and track this issue down.

Comment: In my project I have set android:targetSdkVersion="25", you can try this out as well, otherwise everything seems to be fine!